# Linq - convert an ILookup into another ILookup

Tags: linq, transform, ilookup

This should be simple, but I can't think of a good way to do it. How do you transform an ILookup into another ILookup? For example, how would you copy/clone an ILookup, producing another ILookup with the same keys and same groups?

Here's my lame attempt:

```
static ILookup<TKey, TValue> Copy<TKey, TValue>(ILookup<TKey, TValue> lookup)
{
    return lookup
        .ToDictionary(
            grouping => grouping.Key,
            grouping => grouping.ToArray())
        .SelectMany(pair =>
            pair
                .Value
                .Select(value =>
                    new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(pair.Key, value)))
        .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
}
```

Can anyone improve this?

-- Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
static ILookup<TKey, TValue> Copy<TKey, TValue>(ILookup<TKey, TValue> lookup)
{
    return lookup.
           SelectMany(g => g,
                     (g, v) => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(g.Key, v)).
           ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

Of course, if you want to transform the values somehow, maybe you want something like this:

```
static ILookup<TKey, TValueOut> Transform<TKey, TValue, TValueOut>(
       ILookup<TKey, TValue> lookup,
       Func<TValue, TValueOut> selector)
{
    return lookup.
           SelectMany(g => g,
                      (g, v) => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValueOut>(g.Key, selector(v))).
           ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

Note that this method holds intermediate values in a `KeyValuePair` which, being a value type, is stored on the stack and thus doesn't require any intermediate memory allocations. I profiled a test that creates a `Lookup<int,int>` with 100 keys, each having 10,000 items (for a total of 1,000,000).

- Creating the `Lookup` does 1610 allocations.
- Copying it with my method does 1712 allocations (all the allocations required to create it plus one for each delegate in the `SelectMany` call and one for the enumerator for each key).
- Copying it with anonymous objects instead of `KeyValuePair` does 1,001,712 allocations (all the allocations required to copy plus one for each item).

CPU-wise, even with 100,000 elements per key in the `Lookup` performance between the two copying methods was identical. With 1,000,000 elements per key, the performance was different between the two methods:

- 5.1 sec to create
- 5.9 sec to copy with `KeyValuePair`
- 6.3 sec to copy with anonymous objects

Comment: Nope. That doesn't even compile. The problem is that x is an IGrouping, so you're building an ILookup<TKey, IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>.

Comment: brianberns: You're right, it needs the `SelectMany` step. Note that I used `KeyValuePair` which is a value type, so it doesn't create a new object for every element in the `Lookup`.

Comment: Yep. You and Joe A. came up with (essentially) the same answer. But do you think there's a way to do it that doesn't require instantiating new objects?

Comment: brianberns: Which objects are you trying to avoid instantiating? The only `new` in there instantiates a `KeyValuePair` which should stay on the stack and not produce any garbage.

Comment: brianberns: I just checked and determined that my method only allocates one object per key above and beyond the amount required to create the `Lookup` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
return lookup
  .SelectMany (grp => grp, (grp, item) => new { grp.Key, item})
  .ToLookup (x => x.Key, x => x.item);
```

Comment: Ah, nice. That works and it's certainly an improvement over mine, but it shares the same weakness - it instantiates an intermediate object for each element of the lookup. Is there some way to do it with pure enumeration?

Comment: Yes - LINQ queries will often instantiate intermediate objects. The performance cost rarely works out to be a big deal, though.

Comment: Joe: You are right about the performance costs. In most situations you would need to have many, many millions of items in your `Lookup` before noticing the effect of the intermediate objects because they are so short-lived.